# If Then fomula for a range of dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I have been out of practice with Excel for some time and I am stuck. 
I am trying to create a formula for a date range and highlight. So for example, if the date in O4 is more than 28 days from the date value in N4 then the cell for O4 should turn red. I have tried multiple ways and I am stuck.

Comment: You want conditional formatting with `=O4+28<N4`

Comment: Use this one `=DATE(YEAR(O4),MONTH(O4),DAY(O4)+28)<N4` .

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is recommended to use conditional formatting to achieve your requirements. Choose the O4 and other cells you want to apply the analyzing condition. And click Conditional Formatting in Home group > New rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

[image]

1. If the 28 days means the days between O4 and N4 date values, you could try this formula in conditional formatting: =ABS(O4-N4)>28

[image]

2. If it means the date in O4 is 28 days later than date in N4, you could try this formula in conditional formatting: O4-N4>28

[image]